# rails assets not being required from application.js/application.css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

for some reason the asset files are no longer being required from within application.js/css files. I got these lines in both:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
```

and a ton of asset files in both `stylesheets` and `javascripts` folders.

the app log ( development mode ) :

```
Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-30 17:03:44 +0300
Served asset /application.css - 304 Not Modified (7ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-04-30 17:03:45 +0300
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (2ms)
```

When I check the contents of the loaded application.js/css file from within the browser it has these two lines ( commented out ):

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
```

so it actually looks like application asset files are not being evaluted.
Could you please advice what might be the possible cause?

ubuntu 12.04, rvm, ruby 1.9.3-p194, nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tips:

Those magic comments must be part of the first comments in the file, nothing, not even whitelines must be in front of it.

The complete contents of `application.css` must be at least:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

And of `application.js`:

```
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
```

Also, be sure to hard refresh your application so your browser won't use cached results.

Answer (score 1):

ok, so it's just me being an idiot:

```
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
```

so I've added the blank lines to both files and everything works fine now.

No idea how it has been working before though

Comment: Just had this exact same problem. Thanks for documenting this, it was very helpful.